# Cannot install SQLite Studio on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, sqlitestudio

- I'm new to Raspberry pi and unable to install this particular app.
- I've just got a fresh install of Raspbian OS.
- The site just offers .run file.
- Whenever I click it, it asks which app to open it with, that's confusing because on Ubuntu it just asks whether to execute app or execute it in terminal.
- Please help!

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is based on a chip with an ARM architecture I think, while the only SQLite Studio build for Linux that I saw is for the x64 architecture. In other words, there isn't a build for Linux on ARM.  Maybe SQLiteBrowser has a build for that combination?  https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/

Comment: So, instead I installed the "DB Browser for SQLite", it works the same and even has more features